# How to write html to a page with document.write or other method?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use something like document.write(string.fromcharcode(encoded html.... however as soon as there is any valid html encoded nothing appears on the page. "html" would appear written, but not

```
<html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to add elements to the page?  Or just text?

Comment: A full html page (to be processed not in plain text)

Comment: It doesn't make sense... why would you be writing out the `<html>`?  You're already on a page.

Comment: because there is an arrangement which requires this, sorry for that. Imagine you want to add some html via javascript from within an existing html page, how to do that?

Comment: Your arrangement needs re-thinking.  You cannot simply duplicate tags that you've already put on the page.  I would recommend removing the redundant tags from the source content.  Replace `<body>` child elements and `<head>` child elements with those from the new document.

Comment: isn't there a way to clear the existing html first?

Comment: You could do `document.body.parentNode.innerHTML = ''` if you really want to get rid of everything inside the `html` tags, leaving you with just `<html></html>`. Probably not a good idea and I'm not sure what the consequences of that would be for CSS, scripts and so on.